# Right method for caching in html

Tags: html, caching, manifest

When it comes to caching, I'm not sure which method to use. Should I go with: `.htaccess`

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

or should I rather use: `manifest`

```
<html manifest="demo.appcache">

CACHE MANIFEST
/image.jpg
/logo.gpeg
/main.jpg
```

or does it depend on how I want to use it, since `manifest` has 2 more ways it can be used and `.htaccess` is faster to edit. *greets*

Answer (score 1):

HTTP headers (however you set them, although [.htaccess is not recommended](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) are a well-established, well-supported standard.

The application cache (of which the manifest is a part) is:

- designed for configuring applications designed to run even when the network connection goes away
- poorly supported
- being removed from web standards (service workers, which don't yet enjoy widespread support, are the replacement)

So:

If you are talking about doing standard caching, then use HTTP headers.

If you are talking about writing an application that supports off-line functionality: Use HTTP headers and a service worker.